# Read file and write output in another file using shell script

Tags: files, grep, whitespace, read-write

My input file is:

```
Employee
e_id e_name
100 abc
101 xyz
102 pqr


Salary
e_id e_salary
100 12345
101 67890


Dependents
e_id depp1 depp2
100 qwer tyui
102 asdf ghjkl
```

I want the output line by line as shown below:

```
E100abc
E101xyz
E102pqr
S10012345
S10167890
D100qwertyui
D102asdfghjkl
```

In output there should be starting character which will indicate from which data group this line of data gets fetched.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in Employee Salary Dependents; do
    prefix="${file:0:1}" # First character of the filename
    sed "1,2d;s/ //;s/^/$prefix/" "$file"
done
```